# Using static images to create an animation react-native

Tags: react-native, android-image

I am creating many animations by cycling through a lot of static images, but it seems react-native might not be equipped to do this. The images appear in succession, but become slow and flashy when too many are loaded using require. My question is: has anyone else created animations in this way in react? Is there something in the way 'require' works that might be causing this problem? Is it something to do with Fresco, which react uses to load images? Is there a way to include static images in react-native other than 'require'? Any insight would be helpful!